# Agile Development with Rails 4, Chapter 10 - playtime section: Misunderstood code

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing, ruby-on-rails-4

I am having a problem understanding a line of code in a suggested solution in the playtime section of Chapter 10 in Agile Development with Rails 4.

For an exercise, I am supposed to create a unit test that adds duplicate products. 
The logic of the unit test is as follows: In the unit test, I should create a cart, add two of the same item (already declared as a fixture) to the cart, save the items then make assertions for what I expect the number of items and the total price should be. Below is the suggested solution. The problem is I don't understand this line nor its function: ***"assert_equal 2, cart.line_items[0].quantity"***. See the full test below. Thanks in advance!

```
test "add duplicate product" do
        cart = Cart.create
        ruby_book = products(:ruby)
        cart.add_product(ruby_book.id).save!
        cart.add_product(ruby_book.id).save!
        assert_equal 2*book_one.price, cart.total_price
        assert_equal 1, cart.line_items.size
        assert_equal 2, cart.line_items[0].quantity
    end
```

Answer (score 1):

I commented your code:

```
test "add duplicate product" do
  cart = Cart.create

  ruby_book = products(:ruby)

  cart.add_product(ruby_book.id).save!
  cart.add_product(ruby_book.id).save!

  # Checking that the total price of the cart equals the price of the book * the number of books.
  assert_equal 2 * book_one.price, cart.total_price

  # Only one item in the cart.
  assert_equal 1, cart.line_items.size

  # Only one item in the cart, but the quantity of the item is 2, since we added the same book twice.
  assert_equal 2, cart.line_items[0].quantity
end
```